# Copy data to sheet named in column header and cell named at beginning of row, then loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have some production data in a table on my Source worksheet. In the header of each column is the name of the Destination worksheet, where the data in that column is to be pasted. In Column A at the beginning of each row is the destination column on the destination worksheet; and in Column B is the destination row. Column C concatenates the two to display the cell name, e.g, T138, which would be the destination cell on the destination worksheets. I haven't been a member long enough to embed an image in this post, but there is an pic of the table here:

[image: 1]

So each datum on the Source worksheet is to be copied and then pasted to the worksheet named in the column header and the cell named in column C at the beginning of the row (or alternatively, in the column named in Col.A and the row named in Col.B) Then the script should loop back through the rest of the data cells and do the same for each of them: copy data, paste to sheet specified in column header and cell specified at the beginning of the row in Col.C.

Even though I am a total beginner, I actually thought this would be a fairly simple matter. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I've tried various scripts, but none of them even began to do the job, and they really aren't even worth displaying here. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Worse yet, none of my extensive searches have turned up anything like what I want to do. Maybe I just haven't used the right search terms. "Variable" seems to have gotten the closest to useable search results, but not exactly.

Here is an image of what one of the destination sheets looks like, in relevant part:

[image: 2]

Here's a better image:

[image: 3]

Comment: Can you give an example of the resulting worksheet?

Comment: Each destination worksheet contains production data from a different machine. Each row on the sheet corresponds to a different calendar date. There are three columns available for the data, depending on which shift the data comes from (night shift, day shift, afternoon shift) So it's a matter of copying the data to the correct sheet (machine) in the correct row (date) and the correct column (shift). I hope that gives you a better idea of where the data is to be pasted.

Comment: I would much rather an image/table example vs trying to read and understand. Please post an example result table of what it would look like.

Comment: This is what one destination sheet would look like, in relevant part. Sorry, I'm trying to figure out how to post a link to a pic... one moment

Comment: OK, I added a link to an image of a destination sheet at the end of the main post, above. Hope that works. Thanks

Comment: It helps, but it would be nice if the data in the resulting sheet was actually from the data used in the example sheet so I can correlate better.

Comment: Done. I added a better image to the end of the main post. I really appreciate your trouble. Thanks

Comment: I added an answer, if you feel it solved your issue, please vote & accept so others know it is resolved and also so answerer can get the rep associated. If not, please leave a comment on the answer with issues. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will Loop over each cell in the range of G3 to J and LastRow. Copying the cell if it's numeric to the sheet based on the column header and the cell from column C.

```
Public Sub MoveData()
Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1
'MsgBox LastRow

Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("G3:J" & LastRow)

For Each rcell In rng.Cells
    If Not Len(rcell.Value) = 0 Then

        'MsgBox rcell.Value
        Header = rcell.Offset(1 - rcell.Row).Value
        'MsgBox Header
        Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Header)
        Set DestCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & rcell.Row)
        'MsgBox DestCell
        
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range(rcell.Address).Copy Destination:=Sheets(Header).Range(DestCell)
    End If
Next rcell

End Sub
```